# Query with nvarchar(max) taking 2 minutes to update row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a simple SQL query which updates a single row in a database...

The @SettingValue contains text of about 2000,000 bytes (2mb). This is quite big, but it's not massive, and the field can accept lengths up to 2gb.

The table itself only has about 50 rows, and this is the only row which has this much data.

On my development machine, it takes about a second to write the data, but in production (SQL 2005) it takes about 2 minutes.

I have a feeling that it's doing some kind of page split when trying to write the data.

Are there any tools that can monitor SQL Server to see exactly what it's doing? I've got SQL Profiler, but I don't see anything obvious in there, although I'm only using the standard TSQL_Duration.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Setsetting] @SurgId       INT,
                                   @SettingKey   NVARCHAR(10),
                                   @SettingValue NVARCHAR(max),
                                   @UserId       INT
AS
    DECLARE @setid INT

    SELECT @setid = id
    FROM   [general setting]
    WHERE  [key] = @SettingKey
           AND surg = @SurgId

    IF @setid IS NULL
      INSERT INTO [General Setting]
                  (surg,[key],setval,lastupd,
                   whoupd)
      VALUES      (@SurgId,@SettingKey,@SettingValue,Getdate(),
                   @UserId)
    ELSE
      UPDATE [General Setting]
      SET    setval = @SettingValue,
             lastupd = Getdate(),
             whoupd = @UserId
      WHERE  id = @setid
```

And the table is defined as below.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[General Setting]
      (
         [id]      [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
         [surg]    [INT] NOT NULL,
         [key]     [NVARCHAR](8) NOT NULL,
         [setval]  [NVARCHAR](max) NULL,
         [lastupd] [DATETIME] NULL,
         [whoupd]  [INT] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_General_Setting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [id] ASC )
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
      )
    ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: How is the performance when you try to do the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` by directly giving the values? As for tools, you can try to see the execution plan in SQL Server.

Comment: I guess I could cut/paste the values into a SQL query, I just assumed that it would be too long (being 2mb of text)

Comment: Just for the sake performance troubleshooting, why don't you try with a relatively smaller text first. See if you get anything there. What does the execution plan say? Can you share the same?

Comment: Interesting, if I run the query as a direct command in Management Studio, it completes in under a second.. maybe it's to do with the way c# passes the query details into the SP using the SqlCommand.

Comment: Did you try a shorter string in SSMS or that 2 MB text?

Comment: 2mb.. I'm going to do a bit more research.

Comment: So the troubleshooting went well :)

Comment: Not yet, I now think it's related to the .net SqlClient, and the way it passes blocks of data to SQL.. I'll keep this updated when I get a chance to look at it again.